# Passing two parameters to Express Mongoose api to return single result

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to creating APIs with Express and Mongoose.

I've been able to setup my basic endpoints, get, post, put, etc.

But now I want to set one up where I pass two parameters to search a collection and return a single result.

I don't think I'm passing the parameters correctly.

In my angular, I have the following service call, which I know is correct:

```
.factory('LoginFactory', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/user?email=:eml&password=:pwd', {}, {
    query:{ method:'GET', isArray:true, params:{ eml:'@eml', pwd:'@pwd'}}
  });
});
```

But I don't think I'm doing it right in my express/mongoose API. Here is my endpoint:

```
router.route('/:email:password')
.get(function(req, res){
  User.findOne({email:req.param.email, password:req.param.password}, function(err, user){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `req.params` not `req.param`

and I have a slash before each param

```
app.get("/:email/:password", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.email)
  console.log(req.params.password)
})
```

> [**req.params**](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)
>
> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named
>   route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name,
>   then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object
>   defaults to {}.

You just have one paramater that looks like this `:email:password`. You got to add a slash to create a URL segment so that express can recognize it as a route paramater.